# mysql scheduled events problems

Tags: mysql

I have a table reservation containing `starttime,endtime,status`. i wanted to create an event scheduler which checks whether the current time is greater than `endtime` . if it is greater then it sets the `status` to 0.
but i want that scheduler to run everyday from 6 am to 6pm at 5 minutes interval for forever. so far i have written a code

```
CREATE EVENT rescancel  
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE  
STARTS 06:00:00   
ENDS 18:00:00
DO  
UPDATE reservation SET status = 0 WHERE CURTIME() > endtime
```

how can i make sure that this event runs everyday? so far from what i have read from different websites , this code runs for every 5 minutes from 6 am to 6pm only for that day when event is created. am i wrong? i am new to mysql triggers and events.

Comment: You could run it every 5 minutes the entire day, and have the query test whether the current time is between 6am and 6pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use something similar to check days and times, so you could use:

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE EVENT rescancel
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 5 MINUTE
STARTS NOW()
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
COMMENT ''
  DO
  BEGIN
  IF CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '18:00:00' THEN
    UPDATE reservation SET status = 0 WHERE CURTIME() > endtime;
  END IF;
  END ||

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i think this will work! but according to this code, though the status will not be checked, the event will occur even after 6pm. aren't there ways to prevent the event occuring after 6pm?

Comment: AS far as I know there is no way to run a scheduled event only between time x and y every day. There is a STARTS and ENDS clause, but this is simply when it Ends, and doesn't run again (e.g. I only want it to run for the next two hours).

Answer (score 0):

Test the current time in the query:

```
CREATE EVENT rescancel
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
DO
    UPDATE reservation
    SET status = 0
    WHERE HOUR(CURTIME()) BETWEEN 6 AND 17
    AND CURTIME() > endtime
```